# (__imp_? Name decoration

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB C++ driver in Visual Studio 2015 console application – I get the following error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl mongo::msgasserted(int,char const *)" (__imp_?msgasserted@mongo@@YAXHPBD@Z) 
referenced in function "private: void __thiscall mongo::HostAndPort::init(char const *)" (?init@HostAndPort@mongo@@AAEXPBD@Z)

dumpbin.exe shows, that symbol

?msgasserted@mongo@@YAXHPBD@Z

exists in the libmongoclient.lib file, 
but

(__imp_?msgasserted@mongo@@YAXHPBD@Z msgasserted@mongo@@YAXHPBD@Z

doesn’t. 
I saw examples when function name was prefixed with ?, sometimes saw the same __imp_?  Prefix – but didn’t find the explanation of this type of name decoration.

Another error example:

Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall mongo::DBClientConnection::DBClientConnection(bool,
class mongo::DBClientReplicaSet *,double)" 
(__imp_??0DBClientConnection@mongo@@QAE@_NPAVDBClientReplicaSet@1@N@Z)
 referenced in function 
"public: __thiscall DAO::DAO(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,
class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,
class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" 
(??0DAO@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00@Z)::DBClientConnection(bool, class mongo::DBClientReplicaSet * ,double)" (__imp_??0DBClientConnection@mongo@@QAE@_NPAVDBClientReplicaSet@1@N@Z) 
referenced in function "public: __thiscall DAO::DAO(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,
class std::basic_string,
class std::allocator >,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (??0DAO@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00@Z)

I want to create instance of DBClientConnection class – a part of my code:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

using namespace mongo;

class DAO
{
 public:
    DAO();
    virtual ~DAO();
    DAO(std::string url, std::string user, std::string password);
 private:
    static const std::string dbUrl;
    static const std::string dbUser;
    static const std::string dbPassword;

    DBClientConnection connection;
```

..................

How I can fix the linking problem? How I need to use DBClientConnection class? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `__imp_` prefix is related to import declarations - e.g. __declspec(dllimport). Maybe you're linking against a statically linked libmongoclient, and not an import library? There may be a macro you can define to change the import declaration in the headers.

Comment: Thank you for replay,
Scons  build according to build settings created dynamic linking library, but 
dumpbin.exe /EXPORT shows the following:

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

    384 .CRT$XCU
   1546 .bss
    18B .data
   C4CD .data$r
     10 .debug$F
1784334 .debug$S
 69A0D0 .debug$T
  7411 .drectve
 1538C .rdata
 etc...
What it means – it is not a DLL? But when I try to use it in VS 2015 build as static library also no luck.  How I can find out type of the lib? I know how to correctly put class into DLL and use it – but here I don’t know how to use class from this lib file.

Comment: An import library for a DLL is usually considerably smaller than a static library. And yes, the output of dumpbin seems to suggest you have a static library.

Comment: What you'll want to do is look through the library headers, see if it checks for a macro along the lines of `NO_DYNAMIC_LINK`, and define that before including the headers in your project. Alternatively, make your build script do what it's supposed to do :)

Comment: I fixed the issue - I rebuilt MongoDB C++ driver, created normal DLL, after it Visual Studio 2015 project compiled, linked and now can use MongoDB. If. Details may be provided upon request if interesting.

Comment: For future reference, the macro you are looking for is STATIC_LIBMONGOCLIENT. That will suppress generation of the import and export attributes. But it sounds like you have it working now

Comment: Yes, I did by using DLL form of the driver. Thank you.